# Activity_A start Activity_B with SINGLE_TOP, but Activity_B is created in new task, not in Activity_A's task?

Tags: android, android-activity

Activity_A is in appA, and Activity_B is in appB(Android Settings Activity).
I click a item in Activity_A to start Activity_B like this:

```
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
  mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

mContext is Activity_A.

In some articles, say that activity will push into same task which activity start it.  But Activity_B create a new task, not in Activity_A's task.
Anyone Help me?

Comment: Please refer `Activity Lifecycle`.

Comment: read http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: I have readed Activity Lifecycle and Tasks and Back Stack from Android API DOC,  but can't resolve my problem,  can give me more suggestion?

Comment: please post the manifest for both app a and app b.

Comment: Also, how you you know that Activity_B is being created in a new task?

Answer (score 0):

```
logout.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Comment: Any Problem then told me

Comment: thanks for your answer.   But this also can't solve my issue.
I want Acitivity_A and Activity_B in the same task, but I try for long time, i can't find a solution

Comment: try it  just add 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
  mContext.startActivity(intent); finish()